# Text-based adventure game, attacking causes game to crash

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have set up the function for a player to attack an enemy, which seems to work okay. The problem is the actual action of attacking. In my main game code, it throws an AttributeError.

Here is the block of code that I think is the culprit (at least, this is the block that's referenced by the error):

```
def choose_action(room, player):
    action = None
    while not action:
        available_actions = get_available_actions(room, player)
        action_input = input("Action: ")
        action = available_actions.get(action_input)
        if action:
            action()
        else:
            print("Invalid selection!")
```

The game will run just fine, until we come across an enemy, and we go to attack it. Once I type the hotkey for attack, the game crashes with the following error:

```
game.py", line 53, in choose_action
    action = available_actions.get(action_input)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm new to programming in general, and I'm using a book to help me create this game. I've got the code copied exactly as its written in the book, so I'm just trying to figure out what I need to change in order to make the attack action work properly.

EDIT: As requested, here is the get_available_actions() function:

```
def get_available_actions(room, player):
    actions = OrderedDict()
    print("Choose an action: ")
    if player.inventory:
        action_adder(actions, 'i', player.print_inventory, "Print inventory")
    if isinstance(room, world.EnemyTile) and room.enemy.is_alive():
        action_adder(actions, 'a', player.attack, "Attack")
    else:
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y - 1):
            action_adder(actions, 'n', player.move_north, "Go north")
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y + 1):
            action_adder(actions, 's', player.move_south, "Go south")
        if world.tile_at(room.x + 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, 'e', player.move_east, "Go east")
        if world.tile_at(room.x - 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, 'w', player.move_west, "Go west")
        if player.hp < 100:
            action_adder(actions, 'h', player.heal, "Heal")

        return actions
```

Comment: Most software is not meant to be attacked. I would recommend McAfee or some other virus protection and securing your ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you added the `get_available_actions(arg1, arg2)` function. It appears that this function does not return a value or returns None (which is the same this).

If you can add more of your code we can analyze this error further. Otherwise, you should try to change the return to something can use the method `.get(arg1, arg2)`.

Hope this helps!

With new information from your edit... It looks like your return statement was intended to be indented *one less tab*, review the following code with this change made and see if this fixes your issue:

```
def get_available_actions(room, player):
    actions = OrderedDict()
    print("Choose an action: ")
    if player.inventory:
        action_adder(actions, 'i', player.print_inventory, "Print inventory")
    if isinstance(room, world.EnemyTile) and room.enemy.is_alive():
        action_adder(actions, 'a', player.attack, "Attack")
    else:
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y - 1):
            action_adder(actions, 'n', player.move_north, "Go north")
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y + 1):
            action_adder(actions, 's', player.move_south, "Go south")
        if world.tile_at(room.x + 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, 'e', player.move_east, "Go east")
        if world.tile_at(room.x - 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, 'w', player.move_west, "Go west")
        if player.hp < 100:
            action_adder(actions, 'h', player.heal, "Heal")

    return actions
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for being willing to help a newbie lol. I've added the function you requested to my main post.